# close fancy box from function from within open 'fancybox'

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Hi all i want to be able to close fancyBox when it is open from within.

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
function closeFancyBox(html){
    var re = /.*Element insert complete!.*/gi;
    if( html.search( re ) == 0 ){
        $.fancybox.close();
        //alert("foo");
    }
}
```

foo will open in dialog but will not close down. any hints?

Comment: Are there any errors being generated? Also, are you using any other javascript libraries on the page in addition to jQuery (prototype or mootools, etc).

Comment: See Gavin's answer below for Fancybox 4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74460325/17092

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**Try this:**
parent.$.fancybox.close();

See [Fancybox API documentation](http://fancybox.net/api).

Comment: I had trouble with $.fancybox.close(), but this worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

According to http://fancybox.net/faq

> 4. How can I close FancyBox from other element? ?
>
> Just call `$.fn.fancybox.close()` on
>   your onClick event

So you should just be able to add in the `fn`.

Comment: Haha... I look at the source, you look FAQ. +1 for you being smarter :)

Comment: Looks like they have updated the FAQ to have you call $.fancybox.close();

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to close the fancy box it is sufficient to close it.

```
$('#inline').click(function(){
  $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

It is no use putting the .fn, it will reffers to the prototype.
What you need to do is $.fancybox.close();

The thing is that you are maybe experiencing another error from js.
There are any errors on screen?
Is your fancybox and jquery the latest releases?
jquery is currently in 1.4.1 and fb in 1.3 something

Experiment putting a link inside the fancybox and put that function in it.

You probably had read that, but in any case, 
http://fancybox.net/api

One thing that you probably might need to do is isolate each part in order to realize what it is.

Comment: But this method isn't removing the back-ground div. It just close the box.

Comment: If your background hasn't been removed, then either you created that background and forced, somehow fancybox to use it, or you are experiencing an error on your js, somewhere in the moment that the fancy box is closing. Perhaps you need to try something bold: open the fancy box js file, and put alerts naming each part of that function. The one that not opens, is the line that gives the error. You can, also in other approach, use a try catch statement, and show or write the error as soon as it happens. Just in case, here is how to use it: http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_try_catch.asp. Good luck.

Comment: Just to add some more info: Some js errors that happen to happen in runtime, sometimes are not shown in error logs, if you force it to re-throw the exception, they usually are caught by the error logs.

Answer (score 6):

You can even close fancybox by get close button id and call click event on that id.

```
<input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById("fancybox-close").click();' />
```

It works for me!

Comment: This is quite helpful, could also be done with .trigger('click');

Comment: Since the frame loaded inside my FancyBox had no jQuery references, I ended up using this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issues a longtime then i got the solution by the below code.
please use

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()
```

Comment: Of all of these this was the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an old thread but ...

Actually,  I suspect that the answer to the original question about how to close the window from **within** the window has more to do with the fact that the click event is not attached to the element.  If the click event is attached in document.ready the event will not be attached when fancybox creates the new window.

You need to re-apply the click event once the new window .  Probably the easiest way to do this is to use onComplete feature.

This works for me:

```
$(".popup").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   400, 
    'overlayShow'   :   true,
    'overlayColor'  :   '#000022',
            'overlayOpacity'  : 0.8,
            'onComplete' : function(){$('.closer').click(function(){parent.$.fancybox.close();})}
});
```

Actually, after a bit of thought 'live' rather than 'click' or 'bind' might work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to close it instead:

```
$.fn.fancybox.close();
```

Judging from the fancybox source code, that is how they handle closing it internally.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling myself with this I found a solution that works just replace the $ with jQuery`jQuery.fancybox.close()` and I made it an inline script on an onClick. Going to check if i can call it from the parent

Answer (score 1):

For those who spent hours like me to find out the solution for inline type: window.setTimeout(function(){$.fancybox.close()},10);

Comment: I have problems where under certain conditions (that I don't know) it stays open. Your suggestion is not well enough described. Can you maybe improve the text under what the problem is that you are solving by adding window.setTimeout(). Is there a reason why you don't use the top voted parent function?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
<script>parent.$("#fancy_close").click();</script>
```

I guess the version of fancybox we have doesn't have a $.fancybox.close() function for me to call :(

FYI, I just wanted the page to close the fancybox, as it had finished its processing in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$.fancybox.close()` to where ever you want it to be trigged, in a function or a callback, end of an ajax call!

Woohoo.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for how to close all instances in Fancybox 4 you can just use `Fancybox.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Within an iframe use - parent.$.fancybox.close();

Answer (score 0):

to close fancybox by funciton its necessary to make setTimtout to the function that will close the fancybox
Fancybox needs some time to acept the close function
If you call the function directly will not work

```
function close_fancybox(){
$.fancybox.close();
                     }
setTimeout(close_fancybox, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes in Virtuemart its must be button CLOSe-continue shopping, not  element, because after click you can redirect.. 
i found this redirect bug on my ajax website.

Answer (score -1):

To close ajax fancybox window, use this:

```
onclick event -> $.fancybox.close();
return false;
```