# How to close a jQuery fancybox from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fancybox

I'm using [fancy box](http://fancybox.net/home) to create a popup and load another page on it using an iframe. here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.calendar .day').click(function() {
        day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
        day_data = prompt('Enter Stuff', $(this).find('.content').html());
        if (day_data != null) {

            $.ajax({
                url: window.location,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    day: day_num,
                    data: day_data
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    location.reload();
                }                       
            });
            }
        });
    });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.iframeFancybox1").fancybox({
    'width'           : 800,
    'height'              : 650,
    'overlayOpacity'     :  '0.4',
    'overlayColor'       :  '#000',
    'hideOnContentClick' :   false,
    'autoScale'          :   false,
    'transitionIn'       :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut'  :   'elastic',
    'type'           :   'iframe'
    });
});

</script>
```

It loads the page successfully and does the stuff. But instead of closing the popup form, it loads the popup source form inside the popup itself. I want to close the popup form when the work is done and return to the main menu page from which the popup was generated. How do I achieve this on a button click of the popup form.

Regards, Rangana

Answer (score 36, accepted):

call to `$.fancybox.close();`

also look on this answers in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829319/close-fancy-box-from-function-from-within-open-fancybox)

According to http://fancybox.net/faq

> 4. How can I close FancyBox from other element? ?
>
> Just call `$.fn.fancybox.close()` on
>   your onClick event

So you should just be able to add in the `fn`.

Comment: I have version 2 of fancybox and this did not work...  however, parent.$.fancybox.close(); worked!

Comment: in my case: "Just call $.fancybox.close() on your onClick event"

Answer (score 14):

I had to use `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()` with my **Drupal** site to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use inline call

```
<input type="button" onclick="$.fancybox.close()" value="CloseFB" />
```

Or either you can use function called

```
<script>
function closeFB() {
    // Before closing you can do other stuff, like page reloading
    $("#destination_div").load("?v=staff #source_div_with_content"); 
    // After all you can close FB
    $.fancybox.close(); 
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="closeFB()" value="CloseFB" />
```

Call function in onClickevent

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread but I thought I'd share my two cents.

I was having similar issues with closing the fancybox iframe using the onclick event and after many tries, this did the trick for me: window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()

Here's an example using an input button:

```
<input type="button" class="formbutton" value="Close" onClick="window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" />
```

As well, I tested the onlick on an anchor (a) tag and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

`$.fn.fancybox.close()` doesn't work for version 2.x, in fact, it raises an error. If you're using version 2.x, try `$.fancybox.close(true)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because of my close button has different functions: close popup, and close fancybox. It needs to use e.stopPropagation() to stop bubbling event;

```
$('.close-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

SIMPLE solution, find link to close (it have a class fancibox-close) and do it in 6 seconds (or 6000 miliseconds)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.fancybox-close').click();
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="../../js/fancybox-2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../js/fancybox-2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../js/fancybox-2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script lang="javascript">
        var J$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        function SelectAndClose() {
            txtValue = document.getElementById('<%= _browseTextBox.ClientID %>').value;
            window.returnValue = txtValue.value;

            var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
            // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
            var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
            var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
            // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
            var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
            var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;   // At least IE6


            if (isIE == true) {
                //alert("iexcplorer");
                parent.J$.fancybox.close();
                //document.getElementById("closeFancyInternet").click();//For IExplorer
            }
            else {
                //alert("another one");
                document.getElementById("closeFancy").click(); //For Firefox
            }
            return false;
        }

        function closeBrowsing() {
            document.getElementById("closeFancy").click();
            window.close();
            return false;
        }


    </script>
```

If you want to check your browser must see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/9zxvE/383/

Answer (score 0):

Use default option **data-fancybox-close**

```
<div data-fancybox-close class="btn btn-s btn-small">back</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use event close button of fancybox:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fancybox-item fancybox-close")[0].click();
```