# Close jQuery Fancybox (manually) with a link

Tags: jquery, fancybox

So I've tried using all the solutions that is available on the internet, but doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I'm using (or the project, rather) fancybox-1.3.4, and other than the close icon, a link needs to be used to close the pop-up.

[image]

```
<a id="kpitilepoplink" href="#kpitilepop">Trigger pop-up</a>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="kpitilepop" class="newpopupcontainer">
    Contents
    <a href="#" id="popcloselink" class="blu-btn">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {                                    
         $("a#kpitilepoplink").fancybox({
         }); 
     });                                     
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#popcloselink').click(function(){                                       
         alert();
         $(this).fancybox.close();
         });
     });
</script>
```

The solutions available on the internet is not working, and i'm getting `fancybox.close is not a function` error in the browser console

Comment: have you read the documentation for your version of the plugin?

Comment: @madalinivascu - well the documentation says `$.fancybox.close` which doesn't work.

Comment: you need to call it `$j.fancybox.close();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close a jQuery fancybox from button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398740/how-to-close-a-jquery-fancybox-from-button-click)

Comment: @madalinivascu - I've tried all that. Unfortunately, doesn't work.

Comment: @Shree - You probably didn't read my question properly. I said "I've tried using all the solutions that is available on the internet, but doesn't seem to work"

Comment: @SagarRaj see my second idea down in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has the following method

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

Make sure you prevent the default click event

another solution will be to trigger the `x` close button

```
 $("a.fancybox-close").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip: if you are using fancyBox3, your could simply add `data-fancybox-close`to any element and clicking it will close current fancyBox instance.

For example:

```
$.fancybox.open('<div><p>Hello! This is fancyBox!</p><p><a href="javascript:;" data-fancybox-close>Close</a></p></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to close it on click of "Close" button
//popcloselink is the id of your close button.

```
$('#popcloselink').click(function(){
   $.fancybox.close();
});
```